# Figured-bass accidental only in brackets (lilypond syntax)

Tags: lilypond

In `lilypond` I need to put only the accidental of a figured-bass numeral in brackets--not the whole figure. Does the syntax allow this or is there a workaround?

In the non-working example below, I can put the whole figure in brackets with `< [6-] >` but I want something like `< 6[-] >`.

```
\version "2.18.2"
{
    \clef "bass"
    <<
     { c1 }
     \figures { < 6[-] >1 } 
    >>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter only accidentals in figure mode you get an error. In the [documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/figured-bass#entering-figured-bass) you can read that "Accidentals (including naturals) can be added to figures". So they can be added ("6-" and "6 -" are both ok) but cannot work on their own ("- 6" is not ok).

The workaround is using a markup. You may need to reformat the markup as you like:

```
\version "2.18.2"
{
  \clef "bass"
  <<
    { c1 }
    \figures {
      < \markup \tiny { [ \flat ] \number 6 } >
    }
  >>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion of @fedelibre I tried to concoct a markup that matched the default bracketed figures, but the result is visually unsuccessful, because the markup bracket is not the same as the one used in the figures.

Besides, the code is atrocious. It would need to be wrapped in a Scheme function to be of any use.

```
\version "2.18.2"
{
    \clef "bass"
    <<
     { c2 c2 }
     \figures { < [6- ]>2  
        < 
            \markup \fontsize #-1 \concat {
            \raise #0.2 {
                [
                \fontsize #-3.5 {\raise #0.2 {\flat}}
                ]
            }
            {\number 6}
            } 
        >2 
        }
    >>
}
```

[image]